# How do you install Python packages in Heroku without using pip?

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I am deploying an app on Heroku. When I deploy it, a dependency is missing. I am not able to install it via PIP, since the PIP installation is buggy. How can I get this dependency into Heroku?

Comment: What do you mean by "the pip installation is buggy"? That seems doubtful, it's likely your best option is using pip and dealing with the actual problem you have with it.

Comment: I'm trying to install rtree and the documentation does not mention pip. It can actually be installed via pip but once it is installed it does not work, for some reason. I have read online that this has happened to other people using python 3.* Here's the documentation: http://toblerity.org/rtree/install.html

Comment: Hi Chris. No, I haven't been able to. I have updated the requirements.txt file but rtree continues to not be installed correctly. The only way I got rtree to work is installing it via easy_install in my local system.

Answer (score 2):

You can't manually install Python libraries (or anything else) on Heroku after deploying. That's because [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make to it will be lost whenever your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restartsh) (at least once per day).

Instead, make sure to define your dependencies properly in a `requirements.txt` file (or, if you prefer to use `pipenv`, in `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files). These files should be committed to your repository. When you deploy to Heroku it [will install dependencies for you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies) and include them in your application slug.