# How to install packages with the `--no-deps` flag on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy my python web server to Heroku.

Usually, if I have all my required packages in a virtual environment, I would do `pip freeze > requirments.txt` and upload that to Heroku for installation. But right now this method isn't working because pip's dependency resolutions is causing me problems. If I am running my own virtual environment I can use the `--no-deps` flag with `pip install -r requirements`.

How can I do something similar with Heroku? I am using the Heroku CLI to do pushes.

Comment: The answer here suggests alternatives to manage your app requirements without pip. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843916/how-do-you-install-python-packages-in-heroku-without-using-pip

Comment: "pip's dependency resolutions is causing me problems"—that's worth digging into. I suggest you share details about this instead of avoiding it.

Comment: Here is what I found, two different libraries provide the same API, specifically pycrypto and pycryptodome, but not completely the same. So they create import errors if they overwrite each other. The problem is the second one will overwrite the first one when they are installed in the order pip decides to install my requirments. That however isn't the my desired behavior.